# npm ERR! code ENOENT. npm start , npm install not working

Tags: react-native

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\major project/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\major project\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

**app.js**

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from "@react-navigation/native";
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Home from'./Pages/Home'


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/> 
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>  
        
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "majorproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "expo": "~43.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete nodemodules
the run `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

delete nodemodules the run
`npm install`
if now working delete package-lock.json

Answer (score 1):

delete nodemodules and reinstall